# simplify html css selectors in style sheet

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I have the following html with some bootstrap class

```
<input id="OP_CG1" class="form-control input-sm text-right" value="160"  type="text">
<input id="OP_CG2" class="form-control input-sm text-right" value="280"  type="text">
<input id="OP_CG3" class="form-control input-sm text-right" value="600"  type="text">
```

I would like to simplify to

```
<input id="OP_CG1" value="160"  type="text">
<input id="OP_CG2" value="280"  type="text">
<input id="OP_CG3" value="600"  type="text">
```

by using css selectors. I try this but it does not work.

```
input[id^="OP_CG"].form-control.input-sm.text-right
{
}
```

Can you help me. I want a solution without using Jquery

Comment: This `input[id^="OP_CG"].form-control.input-sm.text-right` would select an element that has _all_ of those classes - Like the first three inputs in your question.  I think you misunderstand how css selectors work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this you would have to combine the CSS associated with the three separate CSS classes applied to your inputs into a single rule...

```
.form-control {
    /* form-control styles here */
}

.input-sm {
    /* input-sm styles here */
}

.text-right {
    /* text-right styles here */
}
```

would become...

```
input[id^="OP_CG"] {
    /* form-control styles here */
    /* input-sm styles here */
    /* text-right styles here */
}
```